# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got an error

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but documents has 1'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Here is my code and I don't known what wrong with my code ;-;

```
   let docRef = db.collection("documents").document(self.txt_email.text!)
                    print(docRef.getDocument{ (document, error)
                        in print("DOC", document?.exists)
                        if(document?.exists == true){
                            print("EXISTS")
                        }else{
                            print("NOT EXISTS")
                            db.collection("documents").document(self.txt_email.text!).setData([:])
                        }
                    })
```

And here is my full Login code

```
      let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("Person").whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    
                    
                    let docRef = db.collection("documents").document(self.txt_email.text!)
                    print(docRef.getDocument{ (document, error)
                        in print("DOC", document?.exists)
                        if(document?.exists == true){
                            print("EXISTS")
                        }else{
                            print("NOT EXISTS")
                            db.collection("documents").document(self.txt_email.text!).setData([:])
                        }
                    })

              
                    
                    
                    
                    
       
                    let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
                    let account = Mapper<Account>().map(JSONObject: document!.data())!
                    ManageCacheObject.saveCurrentAccount(account)
                    
                    self.txt_email.text = ""
                    self.txt_password.text = ""
                    
                    let mainViewController:MainViewController?
                    mainViewController = UIStoryboard.mainViewController()
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainViewController!, animated: true)
                    hud.dismiss()
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code and also an overall design potential problem as well.

This is the first problem

```
self.txt_email.text!
```

what happens if text is nil? Then your code blows up (per your question). The ! is indicating that's an optional so it *could* be nil.

Best to handle that by either using a nil coalescing operator to set a default value or avoiding the call altogether of it's nil.

```
guard let email = self.txt_email.text else { return }
let docRef = db.collection("documents").document(email)
```

Here's the second issue. Firestore is asynchronous and code following a closure will execute before code *in* the closure. So here in this firebase call

```
print( docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
```

the line(s) following that closure

```
let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
```

will execute before the closure, potentially causing a crash in some cases - depending on what's being done in/with data data manipulated within the closure. It may not be an issue in this use case but something to be aware  of.

Design wise - email addresses can contain characters that should be [avoided in documentId's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids).

Also, what happens if an email address changes? You'd have to change every reference to that email in the entire database.

You're structure was not included so I don't know what it is but it's often times best to disambiguate documentId's from the data the document contains. For example

```
People              //collection
   person_id_0      //documentId is auto generated by Firestore
      person_name   //fields
      email
   person_id_1      //document
      person_name   //fields
      email


documents           //collection
   document_0       //document
      email         //field
   document_1
      email
```

so once you have person_id_0's email, you can then query the documents collection to see if it exists. If the email changes, you only have to change it in one place. And again, this avoids issues stemming from characters that may appear in an email address.